pandas_gbq upload dataframe error: Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up
I have a dataframe which I want to upload to BigQuery. The dataframe has 5 columns with the following types and looks like this:
name            object
type            object
population       int32
geometry      geometry
geojson         object
dtype: object


name is name of an area as a string, type is its type (province, city, etc) also a string. population is the area population. geometry is a shapely multipolygon and finally, geojson is the multipolygon converted to geojson using df['geojson'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(shapely.geometry.mapping(x)))
The exact error reads pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 855402; errors: 8; max bad: 0; error percent: 0, so it seems like row 855402 is the problematic one.
The first thing I did was to check whether this row had the same data types, which it does
>>> df.iloc[855402:855403].dtypes
name            object
type            object
population       int32
geometry      geometry
geojson         object
dtype: object

I also checked whether the geometry file is valid and is also is
>>> df.iloc[855402]['geometry'].is_valid
True

What do I need to do to be able to upload this dataframe to BigQuery?

Can you provide an example data?

@Bushmaster I have just uploaded an excerpt of the dataset.

I suspect some of the values have commas in them. So when BigQuery parses the CSV, it treats the commas as separators, and will have an uneven number of columns.

Hi @Winston Li, Did the above comment help to resolve your issue or not ?

As mentioned @user16164298 suspect some of the values have commas in them. So when BigQuery parses the CSV, it treats the commas as separators, and will have an uneven number of columns.You can refer to BigQuery documentation for more details.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.
Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
